# Project Reactor TcpServer -> Process incoming chunked message in its entirety

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have a TcpServer created with Project Reactor, where I want to read in a large String (potentially XML) on the inbound channel, and perform some work on it, and send this back out on the outbound channel.

For me to do the work, I need to have the incoming data in its entirety, without it being chunked. I cannot seem to handle correctly aggregating the data together. Most of the examples in the reactor test code base are just outputting a simple String constant, or a non chunked version of the inbound eg:

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/main/reactor-netty-core/src/test/java/reactor/netty/tcp/TcpServerTests.java#L444

I have tried to String::concat the incoming data like so

```java
inbound.receive().asString().reduce(String::concat)
```

But the subsequent flatmap never seems to be called.

Perhaps there is something with adding a channelHandler, but I was unable to find something that would aggregate, similar to the JsonObjectDecoder

for example:

```java
TcpServer.create().doOnConnection(conn -> connection.addHandlerLast(new AggregatingStringDecoder))`
```

```java
import reactor.netty.DisposableServer;
import reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DisposableServer server =
                TcpServer.create()
                    //inbound.connection.addHandlerLast() Is there a combiner I can use here?
                         .handle((inbound, outbound) -> {
                     
                        //Tried to concat here, but then the flatMap is never called.
                        //return inbound.receive().asString().reduce(String::concat)
                     
                     
                         return inbound.receive().asString().flatMap(s -> {
                         //this is chunked, but I need the S to be the complete string.
                            NettyOutbound out = outbound.sendString(Mono.just(s.toUpperCase()));
                            return out
                         })
                     
                     
                         .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
              .block();
    }
}
```